# allow access to certain directories and files in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http

I have a php application with MVC and **.htaccess** file which rediricte all links to a file index.php 
but I need access to other folders and files as public/css, public/js, public/images annd auther ....

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Most of those MVC rules contain the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This is to prevent urls that point to actual files from being rewritten to your mvc. If you want to link to `public/css` directly, but instead to `/css` for example, you'll need to put a rule before your MVC rule like the following one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ /public/$1/$2 [L]
```

This will internally rewrite `/css/some/stylesheet.css` to `/public/css/some/stylesheet.css`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a condition that allows access to these directories.

```
# Requested filename does NOT contain index.php, resources, or robots.txt
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
# Requested file does NOT exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Requested directory does NOT exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If all the above rules are true, redirect to index.php/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```